# Jmeter- I am unable to sign up using CSS Selector extractor using Jmeter- Please Help

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, css-selectors, magento

I am working on Jmeter for testing a Magento application. I am using CSS Selector Extractor for extracting the form_key element during sign up. I have provided the following parameters in CSS selector extractor[image: CSS Selector Extractor]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Double check that the extracted `${form_key}` variable really has the value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) listener combination
2. Try recording the request for creating the account using [JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), it might be the case your Magento instance requires some custom parameters

I cannot reproduce your issue using online Magento demo version from http://demo-acm-2.bird.eu/customer/account/create/

[image]

Here is a reference script just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.2.1">
    <hashTree>
        <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
            <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
            <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
                <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
        </TestPlan>
        <hashTree>
            <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
                <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
                    <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
                    <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
                <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
                <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
            </ThreadGroup>
            <hashTree>
                <CookieManager guiclass="CookiePanel" testclass="CookieManager" testname="HTTP Cookie Manager" enabled="true">
                    <collectionProp name="CookieManager.cookies"/>
                    <boolProp name="CookieManager.clearEachIteration">false</boolProp>
                    <boolProp name="CookieManager.controlledByThreadGroup">false</boolProp>
                </CookieManager>
                <hashTree/>
                <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="http://demo-acm-2.bird.eu/customer/account/create/" enabled="true">
                    <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
                        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
                    </elementProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">demo-acm-2.bird.eu</stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/customer/account/create/</stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
                    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
                    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
                    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
                    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
                </HTTPSamplerProxy>
                <hashTree>
                    <HtmlExtractor guiclass="HtmlExtractorGui" testclass="HtmlExtractor" testname="CSS Selector Extractor" enabled="true">
                        <stringProp name="HtmlExtractor.refname">form_key</stringProp>
                        <stringProp name="HtmlExtractor.expr">input[name=form_key]</stringProp>
                        <stringProp name="HtmlExtractor.attribute">value</stringProp>
                        <stringProp name="HtmlExtractor.default"></stringProp>
                        <boolProp name="HtmlExtractor.default_empty_value">false</boolProp>
                        <stringProp name="HtmlExtractor.match_number"></stringProp>
                        <stringProp name="HtmlExtractor.extractor_impl"></stringProp>
                    </HtmlExtractor>
                    <hashTree/>
                </hashTree>
                <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="http://demo-acm-2.bird.eu/customer/account/createpost/" enabled="true">
                    <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
                        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
                            <elementProp name="form_key" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.value">${form_key}</stringProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.name">form_key</stringProp>
                            </elementProp>
                            <elementProp name="success_url" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.value"></stringProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.name">success_url</stringProp>
                            </elementProp>
                            <elementProp name="error_url" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.value"></stringProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.name">error_url</stringProp>
                            </elementProp>
                            <elementProp name="firstname" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.value">foo</stringProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.name">firstname</stringProp>
                            </elementProp>
                            <elementProp name="lastname" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.value">bar</stringProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.name">lastname</stringProp>
                            </elementProp>
                            <elementProp name="email" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__RandomString(10,abcdefjkijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}@example.cim</stringProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.name">email</stringProp>
                            </elementProp>
                            <elementProp name="password" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.value">summer@1</stringProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.name">password</stringProp>
                            </elementProp>
                            <elementProp name="password_confirmation" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.value">summer@1</stringProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.name">password_confirmation</stringProp>
                            </elementProp>
                        </collectionProp>
                    </elementProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">demo-acm-2.bird.eu</stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding">UTF-8</stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/customer/account/createpost/</stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">POST</stringProp>
                    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
                    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
                    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
                    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">true</boolProp>
                    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_MULTIPART">true</boolProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
                </HTTPSamplerProxy>
                <hashTree/>
                <DebugSampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugSampler" testname="Debug Sampler" enabled="true">
                    <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">false</boolProp>
                    <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
                    <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
                </DebugSampler>
                <hashTree/>
                <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
                    <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
                    <objProp>
                        <name>saveConfig</name>
                        <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
                            <time>true</time>
                            <latency>true</latency>
                            <timestamp>true</timestamp>
                            <success>true</success>
                            <label>true</label>
                            <code>true</code>
                            <message>true</message>
                            <threadName>true</threadName>
                            <dataType>true</dataType>
                            <encoding>false</encoding>
                            <assertions>true</assertions>
                            <subresults>true</subresults>
                            <responseData>false</responseData>
                            <samplerData>false</samplerData>
                            <xml>false</xml>
                            <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
                            <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
                            <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
                            <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
                            <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
                            <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
                            <bytes>true</bytes>
                            <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
                            <url>true</url>
                            <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
                            <idleTime>true</idleTime>
                            <connectTime>true</connectTime>
                        </value>
                    </objProp>
                    <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
                </ResultCollector>
                <hashTree/>
            </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```